# MIPS: accessing memory addresses with big/small endian

Tags: mips, memory-address, endianness

I am a bit confussed on the whole big-small endian thing.
Let's say we have the following memory addresses and we have a small endian machine.

```
0x10   00 03 02 05
0x14   A3 08 F1 F0
```

if I want to load the first word would I do this:

```
lw $16, 0x10($0)
```

or this:

```
lw $16, 0x13($0)
```

?

Comment: You're over-thinking it - regardless of endianness you load from the base (i.e. lowest) address, which would be 0x10 in your example.

Comment: That's exactly what i thought but i have an assignment which looks pretty simillar to that and is specified that we are dealing with a small endian machine.

Comment: OK - just a little more clarification: the endianness just specifies the order of bytes within a word (or other unit larger than a byte). You still load the whole thing, regardless - it's just a matter of how the bytes are subsequently interpreted.

Comment: is there an opperation that would require you to know what kind of endian you are using? Because i don't think that they would specify the endian for no reason

Comment: In general you don't need to worry about endianness - it only matters when you are either narrowing/widening data, or are interfacing with the outside word (files, networks, external APIs), and perhaps when debugging. The only thing to note in your example is that the value you load from 0x10 will be 0x05020300, i.e. the MS byte is at the highest address in memory.

Comment: I get it, thanks alot. Maybe the specification is there to confuse you.

Comment: Heh - you never know - people who set assignments can be evil!